# How to rotate character's head around the body's up and right vectors?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm writing a first person shooter style camera and character controller. My character model is super basic - it's a rectangle for the body and the cube for the head. I've got a single joint in the head so that I can rotate the head around that joint. In Unity, I've got the camera locked to the head, so that wherever the head is pointed the camera will look.

I have a single C# script in which I'm performing all of my translations and rotations for the character and head movement. I provide the script the `Transform` of my head joint via the Unity editor.

My problem is that whenever I rotate my head around, both vertically and horizontally, the head begins to do a barrel roll. The head will end up upside-down, or in any orientation really. I can understand why - if I look left and then look up, a subsequent look back to the right would cause the head to rotate in an odd orientation for a real head - it'll begin to perform the barrel rolls.

I tried changing the code so that it "rotates around" the up and right vectors of my character's body, but this doesn't seem to change anything. I still experience the barrel rolling.

I also tried changing the relative space from self to world, which "fixes it" so long as my character is standing upright in the world. If my character begins to rotate then the head rotation begins to look weird.

How can I constrain my head to only swivel around the up and right vectors of my character? It shouldn't matter if my character is upside down, on its side, etc, the head rotation should rotate left and right, up and down as you'd expect.

Here is my code that performs the rotations to the head joint. `HeadJoint` is the joint transform that moves the head. `transform` is the character's transform. In this code, I attempt to rotate the head around the character's up and right vectors, but this still seems to produce the barrel roll effect ...

```
private void ApplyHeadVerticalRotation()
{
    var amountX = (-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")) * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;

    HeadJoint.Rotate(transform.right, amountX);
}

private void ApplyHeadHorizontalRotation()
{
    var amountY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * Time.deltaTime * RotationSpeed;

    HeadJoint.Rotate(transform.up, amountY);
}
```

Edit:

I meant to include [this link](https://github.com/ryancole/UnityFpsGame/blob/093299fd59338ab24819afeb441726447a9524b7/Unity/Assets/Scripts/PlayerController.cs#L63) to my script's code ...

Comment: What object `transform` refers to in your code? The head, the body, the whole character...?

Comment: The whole character. It’s the main game object of my character.

Comment: I just updated original post to include link to my script's code in its entirety. I forgot to include it originally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You said you can understand why this happens but here is a [great post](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136174/im-rotating-an-object-on-two-axes-so-why-does-it-keep-twisting-around-the-thir) on this topic on gamedev.stackexchange.
And here is a quick fix: Rotate the head horizontally around the body up vector (in "body space") and rotate the head vertically around the head right vector (in "head space"). Here the `head` is a child of the `body`.

```
public Transform body;
public Transform head;   

public float rotationSpeed; 

void Update()
{
    var amountX = (-Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y")) * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;
    var amountY =   Input.GetAxis("Mouse X")  * Time.deltaTime * rotationSpeed;

    head.Rotate(body.up,    amountY, Space.World);        
    head.Rotate(head.right, amountX, Space.World);
}
```